# Non-blocking function calls with Boost

Tags: javascript, c++, boost

I have this function that is called from Javascript (Browser):

```
STDMETHODIMP CActivexObject::WriteToREST(BSTR data, BSTR* retstr)
{
    std::string sdata = ConvertToString(data);
    RESTClient restclient;
    RESTClient::response resp = restclient.post("somewhere.com", "/post", sdata);
    CComBSTR bstrResult(resp.body.c_str());
    *retstr = bstrResult.Detach();
    return S_OK;
}
```

This method is called from the Javascript like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rowElems.length; i++) {
     var resp = ActivexObject.WriteToREST(_rowToData(rowElems[i]));
}
```

The function works fine, unless the call to REST or the server gets slow, and the Javascript (Browser), i.e. Internet Explorer to show "Not Responding" error box. Then browser shuts down. If I remove the "post" call and just log the data, the there's no such error like this.

Sometimes the `WriteToREST` is called twice or three times.

What could be a possible solution for this that I can make with the C++ code?

Comment: any particular reason you're not sending REST requests directly using Javascript? This is practically the reason RESTful APIs were invented in the first place.

Comment: Yes, because the REST call must come from the C++ code where in there there are security keys that are stored and things hidden from Javascript code

Comment: Erm. That's security by obscurity if ever I saw it. Your security is pretty flimsy anyways if it relies solely on some key hardcoded in the client. And even if so, why don't you just expose an encryption method? It doesn't make much sense to recreate an  entire REST client just to hide the encryption. (I appreciate the challenge, but it's frequently wise to choose how you expend your energy. Basic martial arts)

Comment: I also like how you do a distinct POST for every element, instead of POSTing them all at once.

Comment: @sehe mostly due to legacy code issues :-(

Comment: Yeah, I'd use javascript asynchronous callbacks