# Wrapping long-running function in asynchronous call

Tags: javascript

I have this code that is causing the browser to "hang" or "stop responding" due to the slowness of the call to REST. Browser timeout afaik.

*(This is done this way due to legacy code, in case you might ask why I did not use jQuery or something--where there are stuff in C++ code (ActiveX) that is needed before calling the REST api)*

So here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rowElems.length; i++) {
     var resp = ActivexObject.WriteToREST(_rowToData(rowElems[i]));
}
```

How do I write this into a asynchronous callback where the ActivexObject.WriteToREST call would be wrapped and would not cause a timeout issue? Passing the parameters and getting the response back.

*I can't use jQuery since the Javascript environment which this code runs does not have jQuery.*

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to use ActiveXObject in a web worker, but if you can, great! Otherwise I would split up the row elements and only process X at a time and use window.setTimeout at the end of each interation to process the next X values.

Comment: Can you show us the ActiveX code? It should be possible to rewrite that into an async one (similar to early XHR in IE). What environment are you in specifically?

Comment: @Bergi here's the ActiveX code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357401/non-blocking-function-calls-with-boost

Comment: @xybrek: I can't see anything in that code that you couldn't do in JS actually…

Comment: @Bergi yes there is, the function in the link is merely stripped down code, the majority of code is to get some variable values that is in the DLL, that's why I specifically noted its a legacy code.